# Traverse a data structure in python that involves nesting lists and nesting dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to traverse this kind of tree, the idea is to get all "titles". Notice that this structure can get bigger, it means that every title can get more subcategories in the future. any idea?

I am tryin to do this:

```
def continue_searching(item):
    for i in len(item):
        if categories[i]["subcategories"]:
            continue_searching(i["subcategories"])
            print(i["subcategories"])


def give_titles(categories):
    for i in len(categories):
        if categories[i]["subcategories"]:
            continue_searching(i["subcategories"])
        print(i['title'])


categories = [
    {
        "title": "Food",
        "subcategories": [
            {"title": "Bread"},
            {
                "title": "Meat",
                "subcategories": [
                    {"title": "Pork",
                     "subcategories": [
                         {"title": "White Pork"},
                         {"title": "Red Pork"}
                     ]
                     },
                    {"title": "Beef"},
                ],
            },
            {"title": "Cheese"},
        ],
    },
    {"title": "Drinks"},
]

give_titles(categories)
```

Expected output:

```
Food
-Bread
-Meat
--Pork
---White Pork
---Red Pork
--Beef
-Cheese
Drinks
```

Notice that i am not using recursion because it is not clear for me when stop the calls and i do not want to saturate the call stacks.

Comment: I don't understand this output. Why are there 3 "Porks"? By getting the titles, do you want to put them in a dictionary? in a list? They're already inside a data structure.

Comment: because there are three "title" key with the value "pork"

Comment: I think you had some extra newlines in the pork entries. Does my correction look right?

Comment: Do you wish to print the written output? What is the goal you are trying to achieve by traversing? Is @JohnKugelman's correction the actual output you're trying to print?

Comment: The idea when i execute the code is get the expected output, that means, print all the values of key "title"

Comment: @Nicolas awesome, edited your question to reflect that! :-)

Comment: @Nicolas updated for non-recursive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Define this function:

```py
def write_titles(cats, depth=0):
  for c in cats:
    print('-'*depth, c['title'])
    write_titles(c.get('subcategories', []), depth+1)
```

Then call it using `write_titles(categories)`.

Answer (score 1):

Traversing and printing a data structure like this is usually done using recursion as you've attempted.

In case of your code, we want to call a function repeatedly on every further nesting of the data structure.

Example code:

```
def print_titles(categories, depth=0):
    for category in categories:
        print('-' * depth, category['title'])
        if 'subcategories' in category:
            print_titles(category['subcategories'], depth + 1)
```

---

Since you've changed the question and wish a recursive-less solution, the best one is probably using iterators like so:

```
def print_titles(categories):
    stack = [iter(categories)]
    while stack:
        iterator = stack.pop()
        for item in iterator:
            print("-" * len(stack), item['title'])
            if 'subcategories' in item:
                stack.append(iterator)
                stack.append(iter(item['subcategories']))
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursive programming

```
def get_all_titles(data, output=[]):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
            output.append(data.get("title"))
            data = data.get("subcategories", [])
    if isinstance(data, list):
            for item in data:
                    get_all_titles(item)
    return output
```

Output

```
print(get_all_titles(categories))
['Food', 'Bread', 'Meat', 'Pork', 'White Pork', 'Red Pork', 'Beef', 'Cheese', 'Drinks']
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure you've defined is essentially a list of separate trees.

I just iterated over each "tree" in the list and did a preorder traversal of the tree.

```py
categories = [
{
    "title":         "Food",
    "subcategories": [
        {"title": "Bread"},
        {
            "title": "Meat",
            "subcategories": [
            {"title": "Pork",
                "subcategories": [
                {"title": "White Pork"},
                {"title": "Red Pork"}
                ]
            },
            {"title": "Beef"},
            ],
        },
        {"title": "Cheese"},
        ],
},
{"title": "Drinks"},
]


# What's really defined here is like a list of trees

def preorder(root, depth):
    print("-" * depth + root["title"])
    if "subcategories" in root:
        for child in root["subcategories"]:
            preorder(child, depth + 1)


def printCategories(categories):
    for tree in categories:
        preorder(tree, 0)
    
printCategories(categories)
```

This outputs:

```
Food
-Bread
-Meat
--Pork
---White Pork
---Red Pork
--Beef
-Cheese
Drinks
```

Since you also mentioned that you do not want to use recursion, just perform the traversal using your own stack as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-preorder-traversal/).

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_titles(data, output=[]):

    if x(data, dict):
            output.append(data.get("title"))
            data = data.get("subcategories", [])
    
    if x(data, list):
            for y in data:
                    all_titles(item)
    return
```